# Validate: Controller vs Controller functions

Tags: php, validation, symfony, model-view-controller

I wonder where is the best way to validate the input variables. You could apply this question for every framework, but in my case it is Symfony2: the controller is a class which handles methods like individual controllers.

E.g. I have a Controller Class where each action is a method:

```
namespace MSD\HomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use MSD\HomeBundle\Entity\Imagen as Imagen;

class HomeController extends Controller
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if( isset( $_POST['whatever'] ) && $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] ) )
        {
           $iFoo1 = $whatever * 25;
           $iFoo2 = $whatever / 32;

           return $this->render( 'MSDHomeBundle:Home:template.html.twig', array( 'foo'=> array( 'foo1'=>$iFoo1, 'foo2'=>$iFoo2 ) ) );
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

`$whatever` is validated inside the controller action. But you could create a method for each kind of operation. E.g.

```
private function multiply( $iNum1, $iNum2 )
{
    return ( $iNum1 * $iNum2 );
}  
private function divide( $iNum1, $iNum2 )
{
    return ( $iNum1 / $iNum2 );
}
```

and you should validate the parameters of each function:

```
private function multiply( $iNum1, $iNum2 )
{
    return ( intval( $iNum1 ) * intval( $iNum2 ) );
}  
private function divide( $iNum1, $iNum2 )
{
    return ( intval( $iNum1 ) / intval( $iNum2 ) );
}
```

and call them from the controller:

```
namespace MSD\HomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use MSD\HomeBundle\Entity\Imagen as Imagen;

class HomeController extends Controller
{   
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if( isset( $_POST['whatever'] ) && $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] ) )
        {
           $iFoo1 = $this -> multiply( $whatever, 25 );
           $iFoo2 = $this -> divide( $whatever / 32 );

           return $this->render( 'MSDHomeBundle:Home:template.html.twig', array( 'foo'=> array( 'foo1'=>$iFoo1, 'foo2'=>$iFoo2 ) ) );
        }  
    }
    //...
}
```

but then you're validating `$_POST['whatever']` three times: in the `if` condition and in the two private functions. However, I'm guessing this should be the safer way to validate, because you couldn't 'forget' to validate, since each function validates their own parameters. But also implies duplicated validations.

I'm not sure if there is a better way to proceed. I'm not able to find a better solution, keeping the max security without duplicating validations.

Comment: With symfony you should use the request bag rather than directly hitting the $_POST, $_GET, etc parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree that "you should validate the parameters of each function" -- in your example, those are private functions, as such they are called only by the calling class, and therefore operate in a clean room: whatever calls them is responsible for handing clean data.  As such, the validation as in your example would remain only in the action proper.

That said, I believe validation moves into its own class and is plugged into the form or controller as needed.  I use Zend Framework, and in that I keep my validators as part of the service layer.  Symfony appears to do [something similar](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html), where it looks like you describe the validation as part of the model YAML, then call a validator service on that model.

(Aside: this seems to follow the fat model, skinny controller pattern, which may be [rubbish](http://joncairns.com/2013/04/fat-model-skinny-controller-is-a-load-of-rubbish/).  In ZF, the validation is separate from the model.  More has to be done to connect the pieces, but there is less bloat in the model.)

Comment: In fact, this is not the model, but the controller. All what I've written is about the controller, which in Symfony is a class. So when I say a method, I mean a function inside the controller. Precisely, I'm trying to avoid "fat model" and write more code inside the controller.

Comment: Anyway you slice it, I caution against fattening the controller with validators, for three reasons: (1) goes against the grain of how validation is done in Symphony, (2) controllers are hard to test, (3) cannot be reused across multiple controllers without violating DRY.  So, I would suggest working with the grain of Symphony and putting in a validation service attached to the specific the model class.

Comment: All right. I'll take into account. Thanks for your help. Let me see more answers before accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way is to create your own validators for this.
I don't like this way of validation - in the future you controller will be overloaded with unnecessary code :P
Better try do this like in symfony's tutorials